# How to send a confirmation email when adding a contact to group via API?

Tags: contacts, api, email, groups, confirmation

I'm using the REST API to create contacts and add them to an existing mailing group.  I want to add them as *pending* and trigger the confirmation email but I can't find a way to do it via the API.

The extension [org.civicoop.emailapi](https://civicrm.org/extensions/e-mail-api) seems like it does what I need but it only supports up to 4.6 and I'm running 5.0.2.

Are there any other options?

**edit** - I've installed org.civicoop.emailapi and it's working under 5.0.2, but I can't make it send the group confirmation email as it's not a normal mailing template.

**edit** - If I create my own mailing template, I can't find a token that generates the confirmation link for a specific user and a specific group.  To be clear, I want to recreate the {subscribe.url} token from the *Subscription Confirmation Request* automated message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer.

I was calling GroupContact > Create with parameter Status=Pending.  This worked to create the pending contact but as far as I can find there is no way to then trigger the double opt-in email.

The solution is instead to call MailingEventSubscribe > Create, with parameters for email address and group id.  This adds the pending GroupContact and sends the double opt-in email.

For my use case, I needed to create the contact at the same time, so I use separate API calls of Contact > Create, then MailingEventSubscribe > Create.

Answer (score 2):

We’re using civicoop email api extension on 4.7 and that means it should work on 5.x as well.

Comment: Thanks, I've just installed it and it's working fine.

I'm still having trouble though.  emailapi works to send an email using a template from **Mailings > Message Templates**, but the group confirmation email is not in this list.

Comment: You need to create your own Message Template

Comment: Thanks Karin.  I have tried that but I can't find a token that can be used for confirmation of group membership.  The closest I have found is {action.subscribeUrl.gid}, but this only gives a link to a page where a user can enter their email, and in fact the token does not work at all in an email sent using the emailapi.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer to the question.